# Periodic Behaviour of Loss function in CNN for Object Detection

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, object-detection, loss-function, conv-neural-network

I am trying to train a CNN in TensorFlow to perform text localization in images by using regression to output a bounding box around the text. I have created a custom dataset by pasting images from the IIIT 5K-Word Dataset onto various images containing no text and created labels for the boundary box in each image in the form [pos_x, pos_y, width, height]. Each image contains only one text and the network thus only need to predict one bounding box per image. E.g.:

[image]

From [l2loss](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Illustration-of-IoU-loss-and-2-loss-for-pixel-wise-bounding-box-prediction_fig1_305857552) and [blog](https://leonardoaraujosantos.gitbooks.io/artificial-inteligence/content/object_localization_and_detection.html) I got the impression that tensorflow's l2_loss might be well fitted for this task. However, my loss behaves very strangely by oscillating in a periodic pattern. It looks too strange to be just from poor choice of hyperparameters and I suspect there is something wrong with how I calculate the loss(ex. below). I haven't been able to find much information about object detection implementations other than the more complex models such as YOLO and R-CNN.

Here is my model:

```
# create_batches returns an iterator containing 
(images[i:i+batch_size],labels[i:i+batch_size])
# Each image has size (128, 128, 3) and each label (1,4)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(create_batches, (tf.float32, tf.int64), ([None, 128, 128, 3], [None, 4])).repeat()
iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
XX, y_ = iterator.get_next()

# Define Model
# 1. Define Variables and Placeholders
# Convolutional Layers
W_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 3, 4], stddev=0.1))
b_conv1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[4]))
W_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 4, 8], stddev=0.1))
b_conv2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[8]))
W_conv3 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([5, 5, 8, 16], stddev=0.1))
b_conv3 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(0.1, shape=[16]))

# Densely Connected Layer
W1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([409600,200], stddev=0.1))
b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200]))

# Output Layer
W5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([200,4]))   #truncated_normal([30,10], stddev=0.1))
b5 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([4]))

#Conv. layers
y1conv = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(XX, W_conv1, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')+b_conv1)
y2conv = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(y1conv, W_conv2, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')+b_conv2)
y3conv = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(y2conv, W_conv3, strides=[1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME')+b_conv3)

# Re-shape output from conv-layers
conved_input = tf.reshape(y3conv, [-1, 409600]) 
y4 = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(conved_input, W1) + b1)
y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(y4, W5) + b5)

# 3. Define the loss function  
y_fl = tf.to_float(y_)
diff = tf.subtract(y_fl,y)
loss = tf.nn.l2_loss(diff)

# 4. Define an optimizer
train_step = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.005).minimize(loss)

# initialize
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)
```

After training for 20 epochs the loss looks like this:

[image: Loss]

I tried changing loss to tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.l2_loss(diff)) to get the average error over the batch but it produced the same kind of plot. Is there an obvious mistake in how I compute the loss for the batch?

Comment: If `y` is `[pos_x, pos_y, width, height]`, `tf.subtract(y, yhat)` is not the same as the diff described in [the figure you linked](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Illustration-of-IoU-loss-and-2-loss-for-pixel-wise-bounding-box-prediction_fig1_305857552). Note the 4 dimensions of the bounding box in that figure are 4 different measurements. Not sure how much it matters though. By the way, have you tried the IoU loss?

Comment: Oh, you are right! I think they use [pos_x, pos_y, width, height] in Andrew Ng's course so I just assumed it was the same without looking into it. It feels like it should work like this too so Ḯ'm a bit puzzled. I haven't tried IoU yet but it might be worth a shot, I have thought of trying [link](https://blog.deepsense.ai/deep-learning-right-whale-recognition-kaggle/) as well(they discretize the image positions into a grid and then make the network learn which gridpoint the box is in). I will comment again if it changes anything.